# Odata filter DateTimeOffset

Tags: odata, sitecore

I am trying to run a query similar to

```html
/contacts?$filter=LastModified gt 2022-03-19T12:50:54.219Z
```

To the following entity:

```html
<EntityType Name="Entity" Abstract="true">
  <Key>
    <PropertyRef Name="Id" />
  </Key>
  <Property Name="Id" Type="Edm.Guid" Nullable="false" />
  <Property Name="ConcurrencyToken" Type="Edm.Guid" />
  <Property Name="LastModified" Type="Edm.DateTimeOffset" />
 </EntityType
```

The query seems to work but it is not filtering anything for me. I have also tried a lot of alternatives but nothing works. Think this is an issue with the server?